# Find duplicates in a list

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of books in my application and I am trying to add validation so that duplicate books are not added to the list. The validation should check that the name of the book is not already present in the list, regardless of case i.e. the Lowercase "book1" and the Uppercase "BOOK1" should be treated as the same.

I have written the following code so far:

```
public string Error
{
    get
    {
        if (Books.Count() != Books.Select(x => new { x.Name.ToUpper(), x.CategoryID }).Distinct().Count())
        {
            return "Every Book and Category should be unique";
        }
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

but it comes up with the following error:

> Anonymous Type Projection Initializer Should be simple name or member access  expression.

How should I make to check for the cases as well?

Comment: Is it necessary to check for CategoryID as well? If it is, you probably should include it in your question.

Comment: You could just write a simple comparison method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is in this code segment:

```
new { x.Name.ToUpper(),
```

C# doesn't know what property name to give that expression, so you need to be explicit about what this should be called:

```
new { Name = x.Name.ToUpper(),
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try using a Dictionary, since they don't allow duplicates, using the name of the book as the key.

Comment: He's not really needing to map these keys to a value, rather just ensuring that there are no duplicates in a set of items.  A `HashSet` is therefore more appropriate, since it is just a set of values, not a set of keys that map to values.  `Distinct` is implemented using a `HashSet`, so it's there, it's just not explicit.